# Is there a way to catch both Coefficient and R-squared using Broom?

Tags: r, plm, broom

I'm looping trough several regressions and aim to have a final result with different models, their respective coefficients and statistics, and some general results, as adjusted r squared, AIC and etc. This looping is done considering some subgroups in the database.

As I am using the plm to estimate the results, the broom package produce some nice results to package everything in a neat database. However, their options are kind of limiting. Or do you get the coefficients and their statistics (using tidy - provide p-values, t-statistics etc), or you get the overal model statistics (using glance - provide R-squared, adjusted R-squared, AIC etc).

#### -Is there a way to have both data without recalculating the regression?

I know I can merge the final result, but this would involve double calculation of each regression, and this is computationally costly. I know that the end result would repeat the aggregated statistics for each line of the coefficients, but I don't mind.

#### -Also see that my code kind of repeat the estimations of each regression to provide robust estimations, does anyone know a workaround for this?

A MWE follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(plm)
library(lmtest)
library(magrittr)


data("Grunfeld")

#To generate coefficients by model
reg<- mutate(Grunfeld,
             group = ifelse(firm<6,1,2)) %>%
      group_by(., group) %>%
  do(
     tidy(
          coeftest(plm(as.formula(inv ~ value + capital)
                       ,data= .
                       ,model = "pooling"
                       )
                   ,vcov.= vcovHC(plm(as.formula(inv ~ value + capital)
                                      ,data= .
                                      ,model = "pooling"
                                      )
                                  ,method= "arellano"
                                  )
                  )
       )
  )

#To generate r-squared by model
reg<- mutate(Grunfeld,
             group = ifelse(firm<6,1,2)) %>%
  group_by(., group) %>%
  do(
    glance(
      plm(as.formula(inv ~ value + capital)
          ,data= .
          ,model = "pooling"
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Neither use of `glance()` or `tidy()` "recalculates the regression". Your problem is that your code tries very hard to not save intermediate objects. This results in you copy/pasting lots of code (difficult to modify without bugs) and rerunning the same regressions (extremely inefficient). Just create a list of models, then you can `lapply(model_list, glance)` and `lapply(model_list, tidy)` and do anything else as well.

Comment: As for your other question (it's best to do one question at a time, not combine questions), there's a [whole CRAN task view on robust estimation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Robust.html)

Comment: I understand your points regarding not saving intermediate outputs. The problem is that the output I expect refers to around 200 different regressions. Using lists and "for" loops to calculate everything - plms, vcovs and then applying glance and etc would be very ugly and would triple the size of the code. Also, I would have to keep track of the identification of each model, which would not be saved by the regressions.

Comment: @Gregor The output of `lapply(model_list, tidy)` also is not viable, since it stack columns for each model (for example, you have 6 columns for each model, repeating coefficients, p-values etc), instead of stacking lines (that is - a fixed number of columns which are increased by lines for each model).

Comment: I said anything about `for` loops? Your code looks very long as-is, because you are copy/pasting the model definitions. Your code will be shorter. You will still use `dplyr`, you just need your first `do()` to do `plm()`, call the result `plm_list`. Then `vcov_list = lapply(plm_list, vcovHC, method = "arrelano")`. That already saves you one extra model fitting (since your first `do()` fits the same model twice), is clearer to read and will use fewer lines.

Comment: I don't understand your point about the `lapply(model_list, tidy)`. You can use the `tidy` results as individual list items or you can bind them together into a single data frame with, e.g., `dplyr::bind_rows`, depending on what you want to do with the results.

Comment: I don't have time now for a full answer, but maybe this evening if it's still unanswered...

Comment: Thanks @Gregor, I could work out an answer using your inputs. I'm posting it to help other users. Best!

Answer (score 1):

Using the inputs from @Gregor I could create a satisfactory answer to my problem.

Here it is the MWE:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(plm)
library(lmtest)
library(magrittr)


data("Grunfeld")

plm_reg<- mutate(Grunfeld,
             group = ifelse(firm<6,1,2)) %>%
  group_by(., group) %>%
  do(reg=
      plm(as.formula(inv ~ value + capital)
          ,data= .
          ,model = "pooling"
      )
    )

robust_est <- function(x){
  return(tidy(coeftest(x, vcov.= vcovHC(x, method= "arellano"))))
}

robust_coef <- bind_rows(lapply(plm_reg[[2]], robust_est), .id = "group")
r_squared <-   bind_rows(lapply(plm_reg[[2]], glance), .id = "group")
```